# cmake takes very long time in "scanning dependencies for target"

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, nmake

I have a cmake project (platform Windows, toolchain MSVC 14.1) that uses external components like `boost` and `opencv`. The source files include the headers of these components. I have set the include dirs of these components in `CMakeLists.txt` using `include_directories()`.

When I execute nmake command, it shows `"Scanning dependencies for target <project_name>"` and takes a very long time (several minutes) to complete this step. I checked files `CMakeFiles\<project_name>.dir\depend.make` and `CMakeFiles\<project_name>.dir\depend.internal`. Each of these files contain paths of around 1800 header files. This may be leading to the long scanning time.

Is there any way to reduce the scanning time or eliminate the scanning step?

Comment: Several minutes to compare 1800 timestamps seems pretty excessive. I would guess the time is taken doing something else.

Comment: I tried nmake VERBOSE=2. But it does not show anything while it is doing the scanning. Also on my Windows system it takes longer to do file operations like copy and delete. For example copying a large directory tree takes longer than usual.

Comment: maybe time for a new HD? :)

Comment: The HD is SSD. It is Windows that is slowing down the file operations. However, I cannot change the hardware/OS at this point due to some constraints.

Comment: CMake does seem slow on Windows, I have noticed that myself.